# Getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'"

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the annual and monthly costs via input from the user.  I am getting an error in the `getTotalMonthly` function.  The whole error reads:

```
  File "C:/Users/Zeke/Desktop/pls.py", line 44, in getTotalMonthly
        totalMonthly=loanPayment + insurancePayment + gasPayment + oilPayment + tiresPayment + maintainancePayment
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'
```

The `pls.py` file contains:

```
#Get Loan Payment
def getLoanPayment():
   loanPayment=0
   loanPayment=float(input('Enter the amount of the loan payment: '))
   return loanPayment
#Get the insurance payment
def getInsurancePayment():
    insurancePayment=0
    insurancePayment=float(input("Enter the amount of the insurance payment: "))
    return insurancePayment
#Get the gas payment
def getGasPayment():
    gasPayment=0
    gasPayment=float(input("Enter the amount of the gas payment: "))
    return gasPayment
#Get the oil payment
def getOilPayment():
    oilPayment=0
    oilPayment=float(input("Enter the amount of the oil payment: "))
    return oilPayment
#Get the tires payment
def getTiresPayment():
    tiresPayment=0
    tiresPayment=float(input("Enter the amount of the tires payment: "))
    return tiresPayment
#Get the maintainance payment
def getMaintainancePayment():
    maintainancePayment=0
    maintainancePayment=float(input("Enter the amount of the maitainance payment: "))
    return maintainancePayment
#add up all the payments to get a monthly total
def getTotalMonthly(loanPayment,insurancePayment,gasPayment,oilPayment,tiresPayment,maintainancePayment):
    totalMonthly=0
    totalMonthly=loanPayment + insurancePayment + gasPayment + oilPayment + tiresPayment + maintainancePayment
    return totalMonthly
#Calculate the annual costs
def getTotalAnnual(totalMonthly):
    totalAnnual=0
    totalAnnual=totalMonthly*12
    return totalAnnual
#define the main function
def main():
    loanPayment=0
    insurancePayment=0
    gasPayment=0
    oilPayment=0
    tiresPayment=0
    maintainancePayment=0
    loanPayment=getLoanPayment
    insurancePayment=getInsurancePayment
    gasPayment=getGasPayment
    oilPayment=getOilPayment
    tiresPayment=getTiresPayment
    maintainancePayment=getMaintainancePayment
    totalMonthly=getTotalMonthly(loanPayment,insurancePayment,gasPayment,oilPayment,tiresPayment,maintainancePayment)
    totalAnnual=getTotalAnnual(totalMonthly)
    print('the total monthly payment is',totalMonthly)
    print('the total annual payment is',totalAnnual)
main()
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! it might be more helpful to readers and answerers to put the entire error, including the traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call all your functions by using parenthesis. This is not going to work:

```
insurancePayment=getInsurancePayment
```

You are just going to get the function object not it's result. To fix it you need to:

```
insurancePayment=getInsurancePayment()
```

You also don't need to initialize variables in Python so none of this is needed:

```
loanPayment=0
insurancePayment=0
gasPayment=0
oilPayment=0
tiresPayment=0
maintainancePayment=0
```

You can just set the variables when you need them.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed the problem!

Comment: Reading the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) might be a good idea too.